# Can Google App Scripts access the location of footnote superscripts programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, footnotes

Is it possible to use DocumentApp to find the location of footnote references in the body?

Searching the body or an element using `editAsText()` or `findText()` does not show the superscript footnote markers.

For example, in the following document:

*This is a riveting story with statistics!<sup>1</sup> You can see other stuff here too.*

`body.getText()` returns 'This is a riveting story with statistics! You can see other stuff here too.' No reference, no <sup>1</sup>

**If I want to replace, edit, or manipulate text around the footnote reference (e.g. <sup>1</sup> ), how can I find its location?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the footnote reference is indexed as a child in the Doc. So you can get the index of the footnote reference, insert some text at that index, and then remove the footnote from its parent.

```
function performConversion (docu) {

  var footnotes = docu.getFootnotes() // get the footnote

  var noteText = footnotes.map(function (note) {
    return '((' + note.getFootnoteContents() + ' ))' // reformat text with parens and save in array
  })

  footnotes.forEach(function (note, index) {
    var paragraph = note.getParent() // get the paragraph

    var noteIndex = paragraph.getChildIndex(note) // get the footnote's "child index"

    paragraph.insertText(noteIndex, noteText[index]) // insert formatted text before footnote child index in paragraph

    note.removeFromParent() // delete the original footnote
  })
}
```

Comment: Good! if it is the answer to your question, then mark this answer of **yours** as correct, it helps other users to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getFootnotes()` to edit footnotes. `getFootnotes()` returns an arrays of objects , you need to iterate over them.

You can list the locations (i.e Parent Paragraphs) of footnotes in `Logger.log()`, in the following fashion:

```
    function getFootnotes(){
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById('...');
      var footnotes = doc.getFootnotes();
      var textLocation = {};

  for(var i in footnotes ){
      textLocation = footnotes[i].getParent().getText();
      Logger.log(textLocation);    

  }    
}
```

To get the paragraph truncated right upto the footnote superscript. You can use:

`textLocation = footnotes[i].getPreviousSibling().getText();`

in your case it should return: *This is a riveting story with statistics!* only this portion, because *[1]* is just after the word *statistics!*

Comment: Thanks Br. Sayan. I think my question is confusing because I didn't know how to format superscript in Markdown. I've revised my question to better reflect my intended meaning.