# Google Apps Script: How to jump forward and backward between footnote numbers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, footnotes

I'm looking for a script which move the cursor, step by step (clicking on a "next button"), to each footnote superscripts in the text body?
Your support will be well appreciate. Thanks.

The answer in [Can Google App Scripts access the location of footnote superscripts programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823526/can-google-app-scripts-access-the-location-of-footnote-superscripts-programmatic) doesn't match exactly this question.

Comment: I'm agree that this is not a duplicated question. I want to reopen it. I think I have the answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/fJimPfQ.png

Comment: Just in case if it will stay closed: https://imgur.com/to3mP2f.png

Comment: Many thanks Yuri K. Your code is well helpful. I've tried but I don't know

Comment: You don't know what? https://docs.google.com/document/d/14Ct4NXlkF4a1D28l1HDKdMD6bUboZ_BXvu5EJm4zKwU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've tried but I don't know why it goes up to the second footnote but it does not continue afterward to the third one and so one?

Comment: may be a typo? To retype a code from a screenshot is a quite feat. Try my link from my previous comment. If it will work for you?

Comment: It looks to retrieve all footnotes in your text but not in mine..? I'm investigating how it could be different..?

Comment: @Yuri Khristich
If several footnotes are in the same paragraph, it doesn't move the cursor? Any idea how to sort it out?

Comment: Well. There are some problems, indeed. I'm trying a whole another approach. Stay tuned )

Comment: I've changed your command like this and it seems working
Yours: var position = doc.newPosition(footnotes[n-1].getParent().asParagraph(), 1); 
To: var position = doc.newPosition(footnotes[n-1].getNextSibling(), 0);
But the cursor is just after the footnote instead to be before.

Comment: The original code has one big flaw. It remembers the number of footnote. Forever. And jumps to next or previous footnote relatively this number. There is even the dedicated function to reset the number. But I think the much more natural way is to jump to next or previous footnote relative to the current location of the cursor. I think I've managed to do it. My new version is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a0QraObTtBpvxqvKhWk8P4uo9qxTjNd9o02yFC7hISc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cooper, could you please to vote for <s>Navalny</s> reopenig this question? This is not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich: From your google-docs, I don't get the new footnote menu nor I cannot get access to the script.
I did not find a way to reopen my question? I've edited the question again and claimed that the other thread does not answer. Should I re-ask it like a new question?

Comment: @Cooper. May I ask you to reopen this question. Thanks

Comment: It's strange. It should work. The same menu (without Reset). Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/4t8Qzv96 You can paste it into a new doc, reload the tab and it will work. As for a new question. I don't know. I'm not exactly an expert in asking questions here. ) I'd try to wait, say for 10 hours.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich: Excellent Thanks a lot. (how to support/vote <s>Navalny</s> ?)
Also this command in your original script works nicely. 
var position = doc.newPosition(footnotes[n-1].getNextSibling(), 0);

Comment: Chris and @YuriKhristich Although I reopened this, It's generally  considered rude to ask "Find a script" or "Write a script" for me questions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final variant of the script that does the job:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Footnotes')
    .addItem('Next', 'jump_to_next_footnote')
    .addItem('Previous', 'jump_to_prev_footnote')
    .addToUi();
}
 
 
function jump_to_next_footnote() {
 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var footnotes = doc.getFootnotes();
 
  var cursor = doc.getCursor(); 
 
  // get index of paragraph where the cursor is placed
  try { var cursor_container = cursor.getElement().asParagraph() }
  catch(e) { var cursor_container = cursor.getElement().getParent().asParagraph() } 
  var cursor_pgf = doc.getBody().getChildIndex(cursor_container);
 
  // get offset for the cursor inside its paragraph
  var cursor_offset = cursor.getSurroundingTextOffset();
 
  var n = 0; // footnote num
  
  // function to get index of paragraph of footnote with given number
  const ftn_pgf = n => doc.getBody().getChildIndex(footnotes[n].getParent());
 
  // function to get offset inside its paragraph fo foonote with given number
  const ftn_offset = n => doc.newPosition(footnotes[n].getParent().asParagraph(), 1).getSurroundingTextOffset();
  
  while (cursor_pgf > ftn_pgf(n)) n++;
 
  if (n >= footnotes.length) return;
  
  if (cursor_pgf == ftn_pgf(n)) while (n < footnotes.length && cursor_offset > ftn_offset(n) && cursor_pgf == ftn_pgf(n)) n++;
 
  if (n >= footnotes.length) return;
  
  var position = doc.newPosition(footnotes[n].getParent().asParagraph().getChild(0), ftn_offset(n));
 
  doc.setCursor(position);
}
 
function jump_to_prev_footnote() {
 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var footnotes = doc.getFootnotes();
 
  var cursor = doc.getCursor(); 
 
  try { var cursor_container = cursor.getElement().asParagraph() }
  catch(e) { var cursor_container = cursor.getElement().getParent().asParagraph() } 
  var cursor_pgf = doc.getBody().getChildIndex(cursor_container);
 
  var cursor_offset = cursor.getSurroundingTextOffset();
 
  var n = footnotes.length-1;
  
  const ftn_pgf = n => doc.getBody().getChildIndex(footnotes[n].getParent());
  const ftn_offset = n => doc.newPosition(footnotes[n].getParent().asParagraph(), 1).getSurroundingTextOffset();
  
  while (cursor_pgf < ftn_pgf(n)) n--;
 
  if (n < 0) return;
  
  if (cursor_pgf == ftn_pgf(n)) while (n >= 0 && cursor_offset < ftn_offset(n) && cursor_pgf == ftn_pgf(n)) n--;
 
  if (n < 0) return;
  
  var position = doc.newPosition(footnotes[n].getParent().asParagraph().getChild(0), ftn_offset(n));
 
  doc.setCursor(position);
}
```

It creates custom menu `Footnotes` and two commands within: `Next` and `Previous`. You can jump back and forth between footnotes in document. It's strange that Google Docs has no such option out of the box yet.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.
Your support and contribution were well useful. Many Thanks.